# ASP.Net: setting ValidationExpression dynamically

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have several pages in my form where I need to validate Email addresses. Rather than set `ValidationExpression` in each page , I want to store the Regex string in a Constants class as a string constant and do some thing like

```
  ValidationExpression="<%=Tickets.App_Code.Constants.EmailRegex%>"
```

I know I can do this in Code Behind but I want to do it declaratively in Aspx page. However the above does not work as the text is not replaced by the contents of the constant. In ASP.Net we have syntax like `<%# %>(Binding) , <%= %> (Invoke code)`.

I searched the web but I cannot find much documentation on this area. Can somebody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297822/setting-regularexpressionvalidator-validationexpression-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

If you declared your class something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {

        public  const string EmailRegex = @"\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b";
    }
}
```

You can certainly do this and it will work:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" id="myvalidator" ErrorMessage="email does not have correct format" ValidationExpression='<%=MyNamespace.MyClass.EmailRegex %>' ControlToValidate="email"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Icarus I thought so too. It did not work so I introduced a textbox as 
<asp:TextBox ID="ddd" runat="server"     Text='<%=Tickets.App_Code.Constants.EmailRegex%>'></asp:TextBox>       
The TextBox displays <%=Tickets.App_Code.Constants.EmailRegex%>  I am also surprised but not able to sort out this one

Comment: @josephj1989 it works. I just tested it. Let me post an sample output in a sec.

Comment: @josephj1989 I see what you mean when you say that you used a TextBox. I see the same output as you do, but if you use it in a RegularExpressionValidator works just fine, as I showed you on the pic I added to my answer.

Comment: Icarus, your proposed answer certainly does not work. It's easy to prove failure as shown in your sample, but how about showing success. Both are needed to prove that the solution works.

Let me illustrate:
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ...
            ValidationExpression='<%= Awaken.Web.Services.RegexExpressionProvider.EmailExpression %>' ...></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

results in the following being rendered on the client:

validationexpression="<%= Awaken.Web.Services.RegexExpressionProvider.EmailExpression %>"

Comment: @Ozzy is right, I am getting the same results. You need to prove success (i.e. acceptance of correct input patterns) as well. @Icarus - did you test patterns like `abc@def.de`? Maybe **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9298586/1016343)** answer helps?

Comment: Use `<%#` instead of `<%=` to get the value inserted. Also: Check the generated html and search for validationexpression, to see if it's inserted.