# Setting RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression at runtime

Tags: asp.net, regex, user-controls

I am setting a RegularExpressionValidator at runtime in my aspx control as per below

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revValue" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtZipCode"
                    ValidationExpression='<%=this.SettingManager.GetSettingValue("ZipCodeValidationExpression")%>'
                    ErrorMessage="Invalid Zip Code." Display="Dynamic" />
```

On the page, if I enter an invalid zipcode I do get the message "Invalid Zip Code", however, if I then enter a valid zip code nothing happens and the message remains "Invalid Zip Code".

If I manually set the expression as per below

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revValue" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtZipCode"
                    ValidationExpression="^(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5}|\d{9})$|^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z] \d[a-zA-Z]\d)$"
                    ErrorMessage="Invalid Zip Code." Display="Dynamic" />
```

It works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Try setting the value from code instead, that should work...

Comment: what do you mean? Am I not doing that with ValidationExpression='<%=this.SettingManager.GetSettingValue("ZipCodeValidationExpression")%>'

Comment: That's in markup, I'm talking in code behind... sorry, misspoke earlier

Comment: perhaps you meant.... OnPreRender? I tried that approach, however, I can't seem to access the RegularExpressionValidator and it's properties.

Comment: You can't access?  Is it in a data bound control?

Comment: after rebooting my machine I was able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample code in "Code Behind"**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return "Your Error Message";
    }

    public static string GetValidationExpression()
    {
        return @"\d+";
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            qw.ErrorMessage = GetErrorMessage();
            qw.ValidationExpression = GetValidationExpression();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Sample code in ASPX Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="qw" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="ed" runat="server" Text="ed" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<%=` is not a valid expression for doing this. Use `<%#` which will properly call the `SettingManager.GetSettingValue`'. If the validator is inside a databinding control you don't have to do anything else, otherwise you need to call the DataBind method

**edit**

A small tip: check the generated html and search for `validationexpression`.

```
validationexpression = "<%=this.SettingManager.GetSettingValue(\"ZipCodeValidationExpression\")%>"
```

Which obviously is not the output you need.

Comment: `<%=` does not  seem to be evaluated at all inside `validationexpression` strings.