# How to include a conditional check in my RegularExpressionValidator?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a asp:TextBox which is bound to a asp:RegularExpressionValidator. The ValidationExpression

```
ValidationExpression="\d{5}|\d{4}"
```

checks whether the input has a length of 4 or 5 digits. Those are supposed to be european zipcodes.

Now I also have a dropdown where the user can select her/his country.

What I want to achive is a conditional validation. So if the chosen country is Germany allow only zipcodes with a length of 5, otherwise lenght of 4 digits.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: as a sidenote: `\d{5}|\d{4}` equals `\d{4,5}`

Comment: and I think that what you want to achieve is not possible with static ValidationExpressions :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to change the ValidationExpression at runtime according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297822/setting-regularexpressionvalidator-validationexpression-at-runtime). When the user selects germany you call

```
ValidationExpression = "\d{5}"
```

otherwise you call

```
ValidationExpression = "\d{4}"
```